Filtering a pre-Koszul algebra to get a homogeneous associated graded algebra
In Priddy's paper "Koszul resolutions", on p. 42 he defines an algebra $A$ to be pre-Koszul if it can be written as a quotient of a free algebra $F = F\langle x_i \rangle$ with generators $\{x_i\}$ by an ideal generated by elements of the form $\sum f_i x_i + \sum_{j,k} f_{j,k} x_j x_k.$ If the linear terms are zero — that is, if each $f_i=0$ — then $A$ is called homogeneous pre-Koszul: the relations are homogeneous of degree 2. Let $a_i \in A$ denote the image of $x_i \in F$ under the quotient map. Priddy filters an arbitrary pre-Koszul algebra by filtering the free algebra using word length, and he claims that the associated graded $E^0 A$ is then homogeneous, and if we let $b_i$ be the generator of $E^0 A$ corresponding to $a_i$, then $E^0 A$ "is defined by the relations $\sum_{j,k} f_{j,k} b_j b_k$."
First question: what does this actually mean? The ideal of relations defining $A$ may have several choices of generators, so what are the relations defining $E^0 A$?
Here are two examples: (1) Let $A$ be the $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra generated by $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_{12}$, with defining relations
$$
s_{12} = [s_1, s_2], \quad s_1^2 = 0, \quad s_2^2 = s_1 s_{12}.
$$
The ideal of relations also contains three more quadratic terms:
$$
s_{12}^2 = 0, \quad [s_1, s_{12}] = 0, \quad [s_2, s_{12}] = 0.
$$
These can be deduced from the first three relations that I wrote down, but they cannot be deduced from the "homogeneous versions of these," in which the first relation changes from $s_{12} = [s_1, s_2]$ to $0 = [s_1, s_2]$. I believe that with the filtration by word length, the associated graded will satisfy homogeneous versions of all six of these relations, not just the first three. (In case you're wondering why I'm using $s_{12}$ as a generator at all, since it can be written in terms of the other two: if I use a minimal generating set, namely $s_1$ and $s_2$, then I do not get a pre-Koszul presentation.)
(2) Let $A$ be the $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra generated by $s_1$, $s_2$, $s_4$, $s_{12} = [s_1, s_2]$, $s_{24} = [s_2, s_4]$, and $s_{124} = [s_{12}, s_4]$, with relations (in addition to the commutator relations already given)
$$
s_{1}^{2}, \quad s_{2}^{2} + s_{1} s_{12}, \quad 
[s_{1}, s_{4}] + s_{2} s_{12}, \quad s_{4}^{2} + s_{2}
s_{24}, \quad [s_{2}, s_{124}], \quad s_{24}^{2}.
$$
We can deduce other relations from these, including
$$
[s_{4}, s_{24} ] =s_{1} s_{2} s_{124} + s_{12} s_{124}.
$$
Since the ideal of relations is generated by terms of the appropriate sort, this should be pre-Koszul, despite this "bad" relation. When filtering $A$, we find that $[s_4, s_{24}]$  is in filtration 2, as is $s_{12} s_{124}$, hence so is $s_1 s_2 s_{124}$. Therefore this length three product will be zero in $F_3 / F_2$, so we seem to get a nonquadratic relation in the associated graded. (I don't see how to generate this relation from degree 2 relations.) Is this correct?
If that is correct, then my second question is: what conditions do we need on a pre-Koszul algebra and/or what filtration can we put on it to ensure that the associated graded is homogeneous?

I think you may want to consult less archaic texts on the subject. Here's one where nonhomogeneous Koszul duality is explained in a way that makes sense to me:https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07402 // One thought which may possibly resolve your first question completely: relators are bad, relator subspaces are good. You choose a space of generators V for your algebra A (you actually choose it - it is a part of structure), and prekoszulness is the property that kernel ideal $I$ of $\pi: T(V) \to A$ is generated by $I \cap (T_1 \oplus T_2)$. Associated graded algebra is just $T(V)/(I \cap T_2)$.

I heard that "...it is not a trivial task to write a self-consistent and complete system of relators" from L. Positselski; i. e. if you write a few random quadratic-linear words, then usually it will not a) generate $I \cap (T_1 \oplus T_2)$ as a vector space; b) be linearly independent. It's exceptionally obvious when you add scalar parts to relators -- you can very easily end up with a zero ring; the right associated graded object in this case would be zero ring as well, and not what your bad choice of particular relator elements (opposed to relator subspace) tells you.

To sum up: if you have an algebra presented as $\langle x, y \mid x = 0 \rangle$, you probably should add a relation $x^2 = 0$ before passing to associated graded object (defined as "algebra related by quadratic parts of relators"), or else you will have consequences. If relators are a bit more complicated, this clear issue of working with relator elements becomes significantly less obvious.

Thank you, I will take a look at that book.

Although at a quick glance, I find it odd that Priddy's paper is not listed in the references.
